# Is there a way to resolve a promise before any sub-resolves in AngularUI Router

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have 2 states in coffeescript...

```
stateProvider.state  'test',
    ...
    resolve:
        user: (LongRunning)->
            LongRunning.authenticate().then ->
                console.log("We are authenticated!")

stateProvider.state  'test.child',
    ...
    resolve:
        other: (AfterAuth)->
            AfterAuth.soSomethingWithAuth().then ->
                console.log("We are done!")
```

Of course this doesn't work because the child resolve is kicked off before the parent's auth method has been resolved. This means the second function won't be authenticated and cause the entire state to fail.

Now it doesn't need to necessarily be part of the State path but it needs to be fully completed by the time the resolve functions are called.

How would I make sure the function from parent is fully resolved before calling the method in child?

**Bad (?) Solution**

The one answer I have been able to come up with is to use the manual bootstrap process. However, this is tedious since I would need to rewire all my services. Is there anyway I can do it inside Angular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you use AngularUI Router for Angular 2 or AngularJS? I think that is AngularJS on the fact that you use coffeescript and AngularUI Router. This is Angular tag not AngularJS.

Anyway in AngularUI Router one resolver can depends on another one. Something like that:

```
 function firstStep($stateParams, resolveStatus) {
   return $q.resolve();
 }

 resolve: {
   firstStep: firstStep,
   secondStep: ['firstStep', function (firstStep) {
   ...
   }]
 }
```

Comment: I will add that you can use dependency injection in child routes using all resolved parameters from parent routes. In your example it's in the same resolve - but it doesnt have to be that way.

Comment: Right but by default parent resolves are not finished before moving on @hilnius. So the ones in the parent are not guaranteed to be resolved before the child ones are called. If this makes sure that is the case (adding the relied on variable) works on children this should be ok.

Comment: If there are 30 steps do I have to add this to every step? Is there a way to say 'run any step that inherits from this after firstStep'